# Is iptables thread safe?

Tags: linux, multithreading, thread-safety, iptables

This seems to me to be a basic question, but google and SO fail to give me an answer. As the title says, is iptables thread safe? If I have multiple processes making calls to iptables, should I create a lock for myself?

There seems to be some threads from 2009 querying if netfilter is thread-safe, with no solid resolution. I'm loathe to go check the actual code

Comment: Define "making calls".

Comment: Appending, deleting, listing rules and so forth

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling [iptables](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables), a userspace linux program, so threads don't even come into it, it's a completely separate process for each invocation.  The processes are isolated from each other.  The calls iptables makes to the kernel to update the underlying data structures will be protected.

If you have a multi-threaded program that's spawning all of these processes, then you may run into trouble, depending on your own program's logic.  For example what happens if you add a rule, and immediately delete it?  Whose to say that the rule addition will run before the rule deletion?  One way round, the rule is added, and then deleted.  The other way round, the rule is deleted (which fails because it doesn't yet exist), and then it's added (which works, but the end result is that the tables have a rule that they shouldn't).  To illustrate, here's an example:

```
spawn iptables -A ... (process 1)
spawn iptables -D ... (process 2)
1: starting
2: starting
2: call kernel to delete rule (this is atomic)
1: call kernal to add rule (this is atomic)
2: done
1: done
```

In other words, the atomicity is there to protect the internal data structures of the kernel. It doesn't help protect the logic of *your* program.

**iptables-restore**

Can I also recommend the use of [iptables-restore](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables-restore).   You can then generate a complete ruleset into a file, and load the whole lot in a single atomic operation.  This means that you can never get into a state where what you assume the current ruleset to be is different from what it actually is.  It also means that you are never in a weird internediate state, halfway through updating the rules.

Comment: To clarify, if I make a call to delete rule 1, and just afterwards make a call to insert a rule at position one from another process, will this spawn two iptables processes right? Will the order of the delete and add be preserved? Essentially, does iptables lock the file it writes to, or must I do something on my side to avoid simultaneous access?

Comment: There is no file, iptables makes calls directly to the kernel.  While the updates are atomic (i.e. will be run in a safe, sequential manner by the kernel) there's nothing to say in what order the updates will be run.

Comment: @OverlordAlex If you have complete control of the rules, I'd seriously consider iptables-restore.

Comment: Where is the assurance that `iptables-restore` is atomic? I don't see it in the manual page.  I can see from `strace` that it updates in two transactions: `setsockopt(4, SOL_IP, IPT_SO_SET_REPLACE, "filter\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\....")` and  `setsockopt(4, SOL_IP, IPT_SO_SET_ADD_COUNTERS, "filter\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0...")`. So it looks to me like one invocaton's clearing or restoring of counters can get mixed in with another invocation's rule table, assuming these calls themselves are properly locked out in the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

To protect iptables processes from the race conditions you need to use -w flag enable from 1.4.20 iptables version.
It first checks whether another iptable process is performing its command and if it is then exit or wait.

The mentioned solution only solves atomicity problem.

> **-w, --wait** 
>     Wait for the xtables lock.

To prevent multiple instances of the program from running concurrently, an attempt will be made to obtain an exclusive lock at launch. By default, the program will exit if the lock cannot be obtained. This option will make the program wait until the exclusive lock can be obtained. Posted according to http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables.man.html